# What is a handler in relation to the DispatcherPortlet - Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What is a handler in relation to below statment ?

> The DispatcherPortlet determines a corresponding handler for an
>   incoming portlet request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A handler represents a controller. It manages or "handles" the request, hence the name.